# Scala Parentheses Balancing in Functional Programming

Tags: functional-programming, scala

I was working on the problem to check if the parenthesis are balanced using Scala.

Examples:

- `balance("(Hello (my) name is (StackOverflow))")` -> `True`
- `balance("(Hello (my) name is StackOverflow))(((((((")` -> `False`

The following implementation is working, however I'm wondering: **What would you suggest to change in this implementation to make it more functional?**

In particular I don't like the use of `try-catch` in this solution.

````scala
  import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

  val OPEN_PARENTHESIS: Char = '('
  val CLOSED_PARENTHESIS: Char = ')'

  def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean =
    val parentheses = chars.filter(char => char == OPEN_PARENTHESIS || char == CLOSED_PARENTHESIS)
    val emptyStack = Stack[Char]()
    isBalanced(parentheses, emptyStack)

  private def isBalanced(chars: List[Char], stack: Stack[Char]): Boolean = chars match
    case Nil => stack.isEmpty
    case x :: xs =>
      try {
        val nextStack = processChar(x, stack)
        isBalanced(xs, nextStack)
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => false
      }

  private def processChar(char: Char, stack: Stack[Char]): Stack[Char] = char match
    case char if char == OPEN_PARENTHESIS => stack.push(char)
    case char if char == CLOSED_PARENTHESIS => stack.tail
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given char is not valid")
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Style

### Type inference

Scala supports *type inference*. Explicitly annotating the type of something whose type is obvious does not improve readability. You should annotate the types of your *public APIs*, but other than that, you should use type inference as far as possible, as long as it doesn't impact readability.

For example, this:

```scala
val OPEN_PARENTHESIS: Char = '('
val CLOSED_PARENTHESIS: Char = ')'
```

should just be

```scala
val OPEN_PARENTHESIS = '('
val CLOSED_PARENTHESIS = ')'
```

### Constant value definitions

If you intend for these to be [*constant value definitions*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions), then they need to be explicitly marked as `final`, and they must not have a type annotation:

```scala
final val OPEN_PARENTHESIS = '('
final val CLOSED_PARENTHESIS = ')'
```

(Assuming this is code nested within some sort of main object, for example.)

### Local functions

The most widely-used style for helper functions of recursive methods is to nest those helpers as local functions into the recursive method like this:

```scala
def someComputation(externallyVisibleParameter: SomeType) = 
  def someComputationRec(internalParameter: SomeOtherType): ReturnType = 
    // do your recursive thing

  someComputationRec(foo)
```

You could do that with `isBalanced` (which is only used within `balance`) and `processChar` (which is only used within `isBalanced`).

This keeps your external API clean of any helpers that nobody else needs to know about.

### Naming

I find `balance` to be a strange name for a method that tells you whether something is balanced. It sounds more like an action than a predicate, i.e. like a function which balances something instead of telling you whether it is balanced.

A more idiomatic name for such a predicate function would be `isBalanced`.

### Lightweight control syntax

You use the new-style Scala 3 lightweight control syntax for your pattern matching and you use the indentation-based syntax for your methods. However, for some reason, you do not use it for the exception handling.

This:

```scala
case x :: xs =>
  try {
    val nextStack = processChar(x, stack)
    isBalanced(xs, nextStack)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => false
  }
```

could be written like this:

```scala
case x :: xs =>
  try
    val nextStack = processChar(x, stack)
    isBalanced(xs, nextStack)
  catch
    case e: Exception => false
```

or

```scala
case x :: xs =>
  try
    val nextStack = processChar(x, stack)
    isBalanced(xs, nextStack)
  catch case e: Exception => false
```

## Readability

Do you really think that `OPEN_PARENTHESIS` is more readable than `'('`? How likely do you think it is that someone who reads your code knows what an open parenthesis is, but doesn't know that `(` is an open parenthesis?

## Pattern matching

There is a place where you use *pattern matching* in a weird manner:

```scala
char match
  case char if char == '(' => stack.push(char)
  case char if char == ')' => stack.tail
  case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given char is not valid")
```

So, you are matching against the value of the variable `char`, you don't care what its value is, but you assign it to a new variable named `char` which shadows the outer variable named `char` and then you *guard* the pattern such that the pattern only matches if the value of this new variable named `char` is equal to an open parenthesis.

Soooooo … in other words, you are matching an open parenthesis? Then why not just say so:

```scala
char match
  case '(' => stack.push(char)
  case ')' => stack.tail
  case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given char is not valid")
```

## Pokémon Exceptions

This

```scala
case e: Exception => false
```

is called the [*Pokémon Exception Handling*](https://wiki.c2.com/?PokemonExceptionHandling) Anti-Pattern ("Gotta catch 'em all"), also known as *Diaper Exception Handling* ("Catches all the shit"). It is a serious anti-pattern, and should never be used.

What you are essentially saying is "*Whatever* is going wrong, I know 100% how to correctly handle it". But do you, really? Are you 100% sure that the correct result of a `NullPointerException` is that the string is unbalanced?

You should only ever catch exceptions that you

- Expect AND
- Know how to handle

If you don't know how to handle an exception, don't handle it. Let someone else deal with it. If you don't expect an exception, don't waste effort on handling it. It shouldn't be there in the first place, and if it *is* there, something has gone wrong that you don't understand, so how can you sensibly deal with it?

So, you should catch the exception as narrow as possible:

```scala
case _: IllegalArgumentException => false
```

In fact, with your Pokémon Exception Handling, you have covered up a bug: in `processChar` you take the `tail` of the stack without checking whether there is even something on the stack. This results in an `UnsupportedOperationException` which is swallowed by your Pokémon Handler.

It just happens to work because trying to pop an element off an empty stack means that you have more closing parenthesis than opening ones, which makes the string unbalanced, but that is a very roundabout reasoning that is not made clear anywhere in the code.

It deserves at least an explicit mention, and probably some comments as well:

```scala
case _: IllegalArgumentException | _: UnsupportedOperationException => false
```

## Functional programming

### Immutable data structures

The obvious red flag in your code when it comes to *functional programming* is the use of a *mutable* data structure, in particular, the mutable stack.

You already pass the stack as an argument everywhere, so it would be easy to replace it with an immutable stack (which is just a list) – you just need to also return the modified version everywhere:

```scala
def isBalanced(chars: List[Char]): Boolean =
  def isBalancedRec(chars: List[Char], stack: List[Char]): Boolean =
    def processChar(char: Char) = char match
      case '(' => char :: stack
      case ')' => stack.tail
      case _   => throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given char is not valid")

    chars match
      case Nil     => stack.isEmpty
      case x :: xs =>
        try
          val nextStack = processChar(x)
          isBalanced(xs, nextStack)
        catch case _: IllegalArgumentException | _: UnsupportedOperationException => false

  val parentheses = chars.filter(char => char == '(' || char == ')')
  val emptyStack  = List.empty[Char]
  isBalancedRec(parentheses, emptyStack)
```

### Exceptions

The slightly less obvious red flag is your use of exceptions. Functional programmers prefer to write functions that don't fail. Scala's standard library has multiple types that could help you here:

- [`scala.Option[+A]`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/Option.html) is a type that encapsulates the notion that something may or may not be there.
- [`scala.util.Try[+T]`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/util/Try.html) is a type that encapsulates the notion that a computation may fail.
- [`scala.util.control.Exception.{Catch[+T], Finally}`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/util/control/Exception$.html) are types that encapsulate the notion of composable error handling.

These types have the advantage over exceptions that they are *composable*, meaning you can build up more complex behaviors from simple ones. `Option` and `Try` are also *monads* and behave like *collections*, meaning you can use all the tools you already know from processing collections.

So, you could rewrite your code something like this:

```scala
def isBalanced(chars: List[Char]): Boolean =
  def isBalancedRec(chars: List[Char], stack: List[Char]): Boolean =
    def processChar(char: Char) = char match
      case '('                   => Some(char :: stack)
      case ')' if stack.nonEmpty => Some(stack.tail)
      case _                     => None

    chars match
      case Nil     => stack.isEmpty
      case x :: xs =>
        processChar(x) match
          case Some(nextStack) => isBalancedRec(xs, nextStack)
          case None            => false

  val parentheses = chars.filter(char => char == '(' || char == ')')
  val emptyStack  = List.empty[Char]
  isBalancedRec(parentheses, emptyStack)
```

## Better API

Requiring the user to pass what is basically a string as a `List[Char]` is weird. Why not allow them to pass it as a string?

You can still use your list-based representation internally by simply converting the string to a list at the beginning of the method. Alternatively, you can re-write the list pattern matching using string pattern matching.

### Better internal API

As mentioned by Sara, the way `processChar` interacts with the rest is strange. With a name like `processChar`, I would expect it to, you know, process *any* character. But actually, it only processes parentheses and fails with an exception (in your original code) or a `None` (in mine) when it encounters anything else. Why not simply ignore anything that is not a parenthesis?

Also, as mentioned by Sara, at no point is it actually important what the stack contains. The only thing that is relevant is the height of the stack, which corresponds to the nesting depth of the parentheses.

An implementation that uses the nesting depth could look something like this:

```scala
def isBalanced(str: String) =
  def isBalancedRec(s: String = str, depth: Int = 0): Boolean =
    s match
      case ""        => depth == 0
      case s"($rest" => isBalancedRec(rest, depth + 1)
      case s")$rest" => depth > 0 && isBalancedRec(rest, depth - 1)
      case _         => isBalancedRec(s.drop(1), depth)

  isBalancedRec()
```

### Recursion Patterns

In FP, there are a number of well-known *recursion patterns*. They are actually more than well-known and more than patterns, they have solid mathematical backing, here is just one example of a famous paper: [*Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire*](https://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf91m.pdf).

Some of the most well-known of these patterns are:

- [*Map*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) every element of a collection to a new element ([`map`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#map-fffff812))
- [*Reduce* or *fold*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) all elements of the collection into a single result value ([`fold`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/collection/IterableOnceOps.html#fold-fffff9e1), `foldLeft`, `foldRight`, `reduce`, `reduceLeft`, `reduceRight`)
- [*Unfold*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism) a single seed value into a collection ([`unfold`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/collection/Iterable$.html#unfold-fffffdbf), `iterate`)

As well as special cases of the above, e.g. `forall`, which checks whether all elements of a collection satisfy a certain predicate is "folding" all elements of the collection into a single boolean value. Or, somewhat harder to see, `filter` "folds" all elements of the collection into a single value which is in turn a collection of the same type and a subset of the elements. (Yes, the "single result value" of `fold` can of course be anything, including a collection.)

In fact, it can be shown that [`fold` can implement *any iteration*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Universality), i.e. anything which can be expressed as a loop over a collection, which we know is the same thing as recursing over a collection, can also be expressed using `fold`.

So, what would it look like to express this in terms of recursion patterns? Unfortunately, I am not very pleased with my result. This is the best I could come up with:

```scala
def isBalanced(str: String) =
  str.foldLeft((0, true)) {
    case ((depth, true ), '(') => (depth + 1, depth >= 0)
    case ((depth, true ), ')') => (depth - 1, depth >  0)
    case ((depth, true ), _)   => (depth,     depth >= 0)
    case ((_,     false), _)   => (-1,        false)
  } == (0, true)
```

But I feel that I am missing some epiphany. Also, using `foldLeft` and friends, it is not easily possible to implement the obvious shortcut optimization of stopping processing of the input string as soon as the stack depth is negative, which is trivial to do with imperative loops and with functional recursion.

This solution was suggested in [a comment by Tamoghna Chowdhury](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/262918/scala-parentheses-balancing-in-functional-programming/263244#comment538350_263244):

```scala
def isBalanced(str: String) =
  val depths = str.scanLeft(0) {
    case (depth, '(') => depth + 1
    case (depth, ')') => depth - 1
    case (depth, _)   => depth
  }
  depths.forall(_ >= 0) && depths.last == 0
```

Comment: I humbly volunteer:

`def isBalanced2(str: String) = {
      val depths = str.scanLeft(0) {
        case (depth, '(') => depth + 1
        case (depth, ')') => depth - 1
        case (depth, _)   => depth
     }
    depths.forall(_ >= 0) && depths.last == 0
}`

Sure, this appears to iterate over the string twice, but it does half the work for each iteration, so should be equivalent in performance (minus intermediate list creation) to your idea. Functional elegance and performance are not often compatible anyway ;P

Comment: Sorry for the crap formatting in a comment - [This](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eTZPDFUsQpWZuqrFWFueig) should be better

Comment: Nice use of `scan`.

Answer (score 5):

First off, I'm not sure why `processChar` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` on non-paren characters - wouldn't it be fine to just ignore those characters instead and return the stack unchanged? Those characters don't affect whether a string is balanced or not, after all.

And if we don't mind passing over non-paren characters, well, there doesn't seem to be much reason to remove them in `balance` before calling `isBalanced`, right?

I also find those guards a bit strange, though admittedly I don't know Scala very well. If it's possible to pattern match on `OPEN_PARENTHESIS` and `CLOSE_PARENTHESIS` directly instead of using pattern guards like `case OPEN_PARENTHESIS => stack.push(char)`, I feel like that would be just a bit cleaner, at least for situations like this with a small number of cases. If there were multiple sets of brackets (like if we were not just matching `(` to `)` but also `[` to `]`, say), guards probably would be the way to go

But if you're only matching on one type of bracket, using a stack feels a bit overkill - the only information you're using is *how many* characters are on there, so we could just cut out the middleman and keep an `Int` that counts how many unmatched open parentheses we've seen. That would also avoid throwing exceptions as a result of trying to pop from an empty stack - for example, you could do something vaguely like

```
private def isBalanced(chars: List[Char], unmatched: Int): Boolean = chars match
    case Nil => unmatched == 0
    case '(' :: xs => isBalanced(xs, unmatched + 1)
    case ')' :: xs => (unmatched > 0) && isBalanced(xs, unmatched - 1)
    case _ :: xs => isBalanced(xs, unmatched)
```

Though if you do want to use a stack, I believe you should be able to get similar results by checking for `! stack.isEmpty` instead of `unmatched > 0` in the close-paren case

Comment: If you change `List[Char]` to `Seq[Char]`, and give the `unmatched: Int` a default value, that will achieve the interface that the OP wants, as can be [seen here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Q1mm5jRFTuabwoqtKa2TNw).